# How do I find memory leak in my node.js application on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, memory-leaks, coffeescript

I have a Node.js (CoffeeScript) application (job) deployed as a separate app on Heroku. I have tried using New Relic, node's built-in profiler and heap dump but so far have been unsuccessful. I can not reproduce the data on the dev environment so the only possible way is to run the profiler on Heroku or use an add-on. I need help on how to look for the memory leak on Heroku.